# What is difference between android device id and device token?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting android device id from this code of snippet which is for my device is "3b3472d8998af818"

```
protected String getDeviceId() {
    return Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
}
```

and android device token from this code of snippet which is for my device is 
`APA91bGeA3xOsXocz-eNOklONNVYwHyjvzyVMPQtC54_GX5Npx5fjWjpDbw6XOGqFi-a0lz7gL4BQlZXN-opPyHwJxxo3-1jyqjc1df6y8KwdVj7tUHVObcE3sF0XSpSngUkq6UfCEUTwgmsv-sjGuK863Y4R1kmHA`

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this.context, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
```

I don't know what is the difference between two ids?

Comment: They are just 2 copmletely different numbers, with a completely different goal...

Answer (score 3):

Both are completely different.

[Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the
>   device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the
>   device. (The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the
>   device.)

And `GCMRegistrar.register(this.context, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);` Gives you the registartion id of device from [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html). By which, GCM uniquely identifies the device.

Another difference is [Secure.ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)  may change when factory reset is performed on the device. And Registration id gets changes periodically.

And if you are asking about  [CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) then *This is your project number, and it will be used later on as the GCM sender ID*