# what's the difference definition between token and id

Tags: android, refactoring

case 1:
http session use Session ID or Session token to identify a session. It seens the ID & token is the same.

case 2:
We will see the token & id in Android of android.view.View like this

```
public IBinder getWindowToken() {
    // ...
}

public WindowId getWindowId() {
    // ...
}
```

they must difference to each other, but what's the difference? In code of ourself, when should we named a var ID? when should we named a var token?

Comment: See for this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609211/what-is-difference-between-android-device-id-and-device-token

Comment: Sorry @NayanRath , I have seen the post before, but i still can not understand it very well